# Template matching with skimage: why aren't output dimensions same as input dimensions?

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

In [this tutorial](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_template.html) on template matching with the Python library skimage, there is some simple example code:

```
import numpy as np

from skimage import data
from skimage.feature import match_template

image = data.coins()
coin = image[170:220, 75:130]

result = match_template(image, coin)
```

When I run this, `result` seems to correspond to the input image, however with slightly different dimensions:

```
>>> image.shape
(303, 384)
>>> result.shape
(254, 330)
```

Why is that so? How can I make the pixels of `result` correspond to those of the input `image`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is smaller because the number of possible positions inside the image, at which the template could be positioned without overlapping the border of the image, is less than the number of all pixels in the image. E.g., if you try to align the top-left corner of the template to each pixel in the image, then as you approach the lower/right part of the image, the template would "leak" out of the image. The `match_template` function has a special parameter `pad_input` (and related parameters `mode`, `constant_values`), that would allow padding on the image borders, so that the template could be matched there.

Comment: Thanks for the good illustration of the underlying reasons. I don't know why I didn't find the docs earlier, but I have in the meantime: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.match_template
So `pad_input` actually also lets the output correspond to the center of the template instead of the top left corner (which I find more intuitive).